# wp_is_mobile function

Tags: functions

Let me know whether `wp_is_mobile` function will work with all the mobile and tablet devices ? Is it enough to check mobile device ?

I found that this method in `wp-includes/vars.php`

```
    function wp_is_mobile() {
    static $is_mobile;

    if ( isset($is_mobile) )
        return $is_mobile;

    if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    } elseif ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false // many mobile devices (all iPhone, iPad, etc.)
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false ) {
            $is_mobile = true;
    } else {
        $is_mobile = false;
    }

    return $is_mobile;
}
```

If i need to develop any mobile site, whether i can use this method ?

**Edit**

Why wp uses server side script to detect mobile device ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will fail. There are literally thousands of mobile clients, and not all send a usable User-Agent header. There are [better ways](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50219/responsive-theme-design-how-have-slideshow-on-desktops-tablets-and-static-photo/50265#50265) to adjust the site to small screens (which is not necessary the same as *mobile!*).

Use client side detection and offer a link to switch the view; save that option in a cookie.

I think the common misconception is that mobile == small screen. The [Nexus 10](http://www.engadget.com/2012/10/29/google-nexus-10/) has more pixels than my big desktop screen, while my old laptop running a desktop Ubuntu shows just a 1024x768 pixels. [Surface RT](http://www.theverge.com/2012/10/23/3540550/microsoft-surface-review) comes with 1366x768 pixels, a mouse (trackpad), a keyboard and a touch interface. And some UAs are just [not detectable](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ipad-mini-detection-for-html5-user-agent).

Which one will get the layout “optimized for mobile”?

Comment: Then why wp uses server side script to detect mobile device ?

Comment: No idea. Nobody said the core code is perfect. :)

Comment: Looks like the core uses `wp_is_mobile` to adjust body classes in the admin area and also determine if a given browser can  upload thing.  `shell$ ack wp_is_mobile` will give you some insight -- not that any of those things are really a good reason to use it, but perhaps it was the best solution at the time.