# Show content based on width?

Tags: responsive

Is it possible to show content based on width of page/screen?

I would like to show part of the header and footer only when the paged is shown in full width and then have it go away when used on smaller screen/mobile/pad.

The best thing would be able to use a responsive theme and have areas above and below that only shows when using "full screen" = 1000px.

---

[FIXED AREA SHOWN ONLY WHEN WIDTH IS 1000+ PX]

Responsive theme

[FIXED AREA SHOWN ONLY WHEN WIDTH IS 1000+ PX]

---

Best regards,
Mikael

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50265/73)?

Answer (score 0):

As you said making a part responsive would be the best way you can choose.
Working with `screen width` is some thing client side, and that's done by `CSS` or alternatively by `Javascript`.

If it's related to css, `media queries` will do the job:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-cssqueries/index.html

and if it's js, `width` property of `screen` object does the trick:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look. I have also updated my question above with more information.