# Using subdomain m.website.com for mobile theme?

Tags: subdomains, mobile

Can we have a sub-domain m.website.com for mobile users, those are automatically redirected to it?

And what's the purpose anyway?

Comment: That's the purpose, to serve optimized website for mobile and handheld devices.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a subdomain, but you cannot detect mobile users reliably. And you shouldn’t.

#### How to use a subdomain with the same content

In your `wp-config.php`, look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. If it matches `m.example.com`, enforce the current domain as main domain with …

```
const DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE = 'm.example.com';
```

… and filter the active theme:

```
add_filter( 'stylesheet', function( $stylesheet ) {

    if ( 'm.example.com' === DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE )
        return 'mobile-theme';

    return $stylesheet;
});
```

Set up redirections for `/wp-admin/` and `wp-login.php`, so authors cannot *write* on the mobile site.

#### Why you should not do that

Detecting mobile users is hard work. You cannot trust user agent strings, because they lie, are empty, or they contain malicious code. Never use `wp_is_mobile()`, this is embarrassingly naïve.

Being on a mobile device doesn’t mean that a small screen or low bandwidth is used.

The separate subdomains are a thing of the past. They were used when browsers could not handle [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), and mobile were all small and slow. This isn’t true anymore, so please don’t start building a dinosaur.

See also: [How to load content per AJAX depending on screen size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50265/73).

Comment: How else to detect for mobile? For example, using mobile-based ads on a page where the only control over the ad is which tag gets called. The theme itself is responsive, but including, say, Flash-based ads for desktop and text-based ads for mobile?

Comment: @JonMitten I have added a link for that. I don’t see any reason to deliver Flash to anyone.

Comment: While I agree in principle that Flash is unnecessary, content publishers don't necessarily have the flexibility or control over their ad feeds where they can pick and choose which ads get delivered.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather considering just making your site perfectly responsive, subdomains for mobile websites are thing of past, but some big website do still rely on it.

Not because they want a mobile site, but because some of their main website features are yet not something that a mobile device should be left to handle.

We are now at a stage where applications(here : Web Apps) are platform independent, irrespective of the device they are run on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't literally use another theme on the same installation, but "theme" is just an abstraction after all, it can be made of an unlimited number of completely different templates, so... What you CAN do is trick Wordpress into thinking it's the same theme. A bit quirky, but otherwise fairly easy.

Big caveat: If you're looking to install an off-the-shelf theme, it's probably not worth the trouble, most likely some components down the road will break. Another caveat: Urls will become duplicate, so you may want to either properly set up wp-config to account for this, or rewrite them on the fly or maybe just set up canonicals

But if it's something purpose made, or a very simple cleanly-crafted theme or just prototyping, it works nicely.

So you have your fresh subdomain. All you have to do here is create an index.php, with a single line pointing to your main installation:
require `('/your/path/to/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Great progress already! At this point, your subdomain mirrors your website.

Now you want to display something else there. Add this to your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'subdomain_theme', 99 );
function subdomain_theme( $template ) {
$uri = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    if (strpos($uri,'yoursubdomain.') !== FALSE) {
    $new_template = '/your/path/to/wp/wp-content/themes/your-subdomain-theme/index.php';
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

And now you have your 'basic theme' up and running!

If you want to use more templates than just index.php, you'll have to rebuild some of the wp template logic. So, create a new file in your theme directory and point to it. The relevant line from above becomes:

```
$new_template = '/your/path/to/wp/wp-content/themes/your-subdomain-theme/whatever.php';
```

And inside whatever.php point to each actual template in part:

```
if(is_single()) {include('/home/standard.wp/wp-content/themes/feeds/single.php');}
elseif (is_home()) { // ... easy from here
```

And there's your subdomain separate theme running on the same no-multisite wp instance.