# How to install seperate theme on certain page

Tags: multisite

My question pertains to the latest version of WordPress.

I am looking to have a two themes on under 1 domain.

In other words

www.abc.com will have one theme present.
www.abc.com/about will have a completely separate theme..

Its the same concept as Wordpress Theme sites, they will have 10-30 different layouts, and are able to 'demo' each layout under the same domain.

I am wanting to showcase different examples under 1 www.abc.com domain.

If anyone can provide additional information, or even what I should be searching for (method definition) I would greatly appreciate it.

tl;dr

I have heard of subdomain, and subdirectory. I just want to be able to have a friend go to abc.com/example1 and abc.com/example2 to showcase different theme layouts for them, what is the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: If all want is to have a different look for `/about`, using Multisite is probably overkill. You'd probably be further ahead to look into [Custom Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates).

Comment: Maybe it is only me but it is not clear what exactly are you asking? if it is whether you should use multisite for that the answer is yes.

Comment: see here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174117/using-subdomain-m-website-com-for-mobile-theme/400770#400770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist two cases in your question. 
1. You want different theme for different pages of single WordPress site. You can achieve this using a plugin - [Multiple Themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/)

2. You want different sites having different admin dashboard and different theme for each site. Then you must use MultiSite.